# Why apache does not load document root from httpd.conf

Tags: macos, apache, httpd.conf

I have apache running on my local machine (Mac OS X)

that listens to port 80:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 Server at localhost Port 80
```

I am able to stop the server with `sudo apachectl -v stop` and to start it again
but can't find or update the document root.

tried the following:

```
sudo apachectl -V | grep -i SERVER_CONFIG_FILE | cut -f2 -d'"' | xargs grep -i '^DocumentRoot' | cut -f2 -d'"'
```

to print out document roots from .conf file and it returned:

```
DocumentRoot /var/empty
/Library/WebServer/Documents
```

Tried to create test files for the web server to serve

```
echo 'Hello World1!' > /var/empty/index.html
echo 'Hello World2!' > /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html
```

restarted apache but "Hello World" still not showing up just the 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Sharing option in System Preferences -> sharing wasn't enabled

[image]

If you are having the same problem but your sharing pannel does not have a "Web Sharing" option you can try to follow the [CLICKONTYLER blog post](http://clickontyler.com/blog/2012/02/web-sharing-mountain-lion/)

Comment: Web sharing option not in System Preferences/Sharing/

Comment: was taken out in Mountain Lion